# How to extract domain from email address with Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have no idea to extract domain part from email address with pandas. In case if it is 'kkk@gmail.com' I would like to get 'gmail.com'.

Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second value of lists by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['kkk@gmail.com','aa@yahoo.com']})

df['domain'] = df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]
#faster solution if no NaNs values 
#df['domain'] = [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['email']]
print (df)
           email     domain
0  kkk@gmail.com  gmail.com
1   aa@yahoo.com  yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using lambda function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['aaa@gmail.com','bbb@yahoo.com', 'ccc@aol.com']})

df['domain'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.split('@')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Though both answers are useful, I did some checking on which one is the fastest.
From the answers provided by Jezrael and Akhilesh only Jezrael's first method is robust against nan values.
However, Akhilesh' answer is the fastest by quite a margin.

Timing was done as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['kkk@gmail.com','aa@yahoo.com']})

def method1():
    df['domain'] = df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]
    return df

def method2():
    df['domain'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x.split('@')[1])
    return df

def method3():
    df['domain'] = [x.split('@')[1] for x in df['email']]

print('Time for method 1:', timeit.timeit(method1, number=100000))
print('Time for method 2:', timeit.timeit(method2, number=100000))
print('Time for method 3:', timeit.timeit(method3, number=100000))
```

Results with nan values:

- Method 1: 16.07 seconds.
- Method 2: Error.
- Method 3: Error.

Results without nan values:

- Method 1: 15.88 seconds.
- Method 2: 9.03 seconds.
- Method 3: 4.04 seconds.